# Best way to attach WAF with different rules for production and non-production env

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, web-application-firewall

We have CloudFront in front of the s3 bucket that serves our static files. We would like to add WAF to our non-production environments with certain rules such as block traffic from outside IPs other than corporate VPN but not on the production WAF.

What is the best way to manage it in the Serverless framework?

Answer (score 1):

you can create the acl via the aws console or using [cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webacl.html)

in both cases, to associate it in your project, you can use [serverless-associate-waf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-associate-waf)

in the `resources:` section you could also declare the acl cloudformation and associate it to the api gateway generated by serverless using the [`AWS::WAFv2::WebACLAssociation`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webaclassociation.html) resource type

if you decide to declare the acl cloudformation in the `resources:` section, you can use the `stage` variable (e.g. dev/prod) to decide when to associate it with your api resource

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-associate-waf seems to do it with API gateway. Our front-end project is just S3 and cloudfront. There is no API gateway for the FE application